# How to save 'arrays' to variable from QueryDict

Tags: python, django

I have a following structure of QueryDict:

`QueryDict: {u'tab[1][val1]': [u'val1'], u'tab[1][val2]': [u'val2'], u'tab[0][val1]': [u'val1'], u'tab[1][val2]': [u'val2']}`

I want to store it in an iterable variable so I can do something like this:

```
for x in xs:
   do_something(x.get('val1'))
```

where x is tab[0] etc

I tried:

```
dict(request.POST._iteritems())
```

but it doesn't return tab[0] but tab[0][val1] as an element.
Is it possible to store entire tab[idx] in variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) has a few additional methods to deal with multiple values per key compared to the traditional `dict`; useful for your purposes are:

> `QueryDict.iterlists()` Like `QueryDict.iteritems()` except it includes
>   all values, as a list, for each member of the dictionary.
>
> `QueryDict.getlist(key, default)`
>   Returns the data with the requested key, as a Python list. Returns an empty list if the key doesn’t exist and no default value was provided. It’s guaranteed to return a list of some sort unless the default value was no list.
>
> `QueryDict.lists()`
>   Like items(), except it includes all values, as a list, for each member of the dictionary.

So you can do something like:

```
qd = QueryDict(...)
for values in qd.lists():
    for value in values:
        do_something(value)
```

Also note that the "normal" dict methods like `get` always return only a single value (the last value for that key).